# Using SSL with the FAST 2010 Content API

Tags: fast-search

Using the FAST Content API with Sharepoint 2010 requires a SSL client certificate . At least that's what I understand from this error message"

> Http error: HTTP/1.1 403 Could not verify client certificate.

I can configure my client to use a SSL certificate, but how do I import that into FAST? Since the content API ports are not handled by IIS, I can only assume that this is a FAST-specific configuration procedure.

---

*Update*: I've made the following steps:

1. Generated a public+private key pair with the Java `keytool` application
2. I've converted that keystore to to a PCKS12 (PFX) keystore which can be imported by Windows
3. I've tried to import the keystore using the instructions for setting up SSL between FAST and Sharepoint, but I get a cryptic error

I can't make heads or tails of this but I can confirm that the certificate is installed alongside the `FastSearchCert` certificate in the *Certificates (Local Computer) -> Personal -> Certificates* Snap-In.

Note that the FAST machine is part of an AD, while the machine which generated the certificate is not.

```
PS C:\FASTSearch\Installer\scripts> .\securefastsearchconnector.ps1 -certPath c:\windows\temp\java-client-cert.pfx -ssaName FASTContent -username "CORP\Administrator"
Enter the certificate password: ******** 
Installed certificate.
Could not set access rights on certificates private keys. Script can be rerun to only set access rights when reason for error is detected.
Get-Acl : Cannot find path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6c8c8677fca4d588e808522374fc60aa_6c6a2f58-dc6a-42a6-80ac-19d3b57cafb5' because it does not exist.
At C:\FASTSearch\Installer\scripts\securefastsearchconnector.ps1:157 char:17
+         $acl = Get-Acl <<<<  $keypath$keyname
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip ssl verification in content api by using this code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certifcate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Insert it before using api calls.

Comment: if I understand correctly ( I'm using Java in my client calls ) this allows the client to not validate the Server's certificate. But in my case the server requires that the client present a SSL certificate.

Comment: To understand you correctly, you are using Java to pass content on to FAST, not the .NET content api?

Comment: @Mikael-SharePointMVP - that's correct

Comment: @RobertMunteanu I'm not sure that is supported. I think only the .NET Content API is supported as it wraps the internal logic needed to talk to the content distributor. The old ESP API's are not 100% the same and will not work. If you read the docs for the .NET API I think it mentions how to set up the certificate it uses, and you might be able to use that information to set it up certificates correctly in JAVA, but might not be that easy.

Comment: @Mikael-SharePointMVP I have the Java API working just fine or HTTP but not HTTPS. The Java API is bundled with the Fast search server installation and the old FAST ESP API definitely does not work. I've followed the old FAST ESP SSL guide, but after generating my old certificate signing request I am not sure how to sign it.

Comment: Thinking about it, java should work as the database connector uses it. If you follow the sample for .NET, it adds the thumbprint of the cert used when setting up https and passes this to the factory method of CreateDocumentFeeder. See C:\Program Files\Content API for Microsoft FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint\v1.0.15\examples\ContentAPIExample\ContentAPIExample.cs and the App.config file. Does that help, or have you already looked at it?

Comment: @Mikael-SharePointMVP - I've seen those examples ; Java is not that well integrated with the Windows keystore ,so a thumbprint is not enough . I've managed to make it work by exporting the Java application's keystore as a PFX ( PKCS12 ) file and importing it into the server keystore of the server running FAST. I'll post this as an answer when I have the process documented.